# залить цветом тайл карты leaflet

Tags: leafletjs

Использую js leaflet для своей карты, наткнулся на [данный сервис](http://coinmap.org/#/map/55.73851531/37.64538288/16), понравилось как выглядят их тайлы, точнее заливка карты голубым тоном, хотел "позаимствовать" тайлы, а они в [исходном состоянии](https://cartodb-basemaps-b.global.ssl.fastly.net/#16/55.7382/37.6476) в сером цвете (lightAll), и никак не могу понять как они их "покрасили", как это реализовано? кто сталкивался с такой фичей? 
[image: Покрашенный вариант][image: Оригинал]

Comment: Есть расширение, которое использует пиксельный шейдер для каждого тайла

Comment: https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается всё гораздо проще, в примере выше используется css на каждый тайл, а конкретно классу .map .leaflet-tile-pane применяется filter:saturate(4)